# Conditional token pattern

Tags: 7, hooks, tokens

I am looking for a module or a hook that allow me to use if conditions with tokens.

For example I want to check if a field is equal to a specific value or text

[if][field_name][eq]hello[then][field_name_alt]

any ideas will be helpful.

Comment: You has tried with hook_token ?

Comment: @vinhdv its been a long time since I posted this question. I didn't try hook_token for this issue. I remember I wrote a module to solve my issue at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea, which I have not tried yet.

Sometimes you have tokens in combination with text formats. E.g. in `commerce_checkout_completion_message_pane_checkout_form()` the token replacement happens first, before the text format is applied. I am not sure if I agree with this order, but in this case it gives us some interesting options.

You could define a custom text filter which detects and evaluates markup like this:

```
{if true}hello{else}goodbye{endif}
```

and then you can use tokens to insert the true/false.

```
{if [token-which-returns-true-or-false]}hello{else}goodbye{endif}
```

This still leaves a lot in the open. Most tokens do not produce true/false, so maybe instead you want real equation formulas. But it is a direction you can explore further.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to build it with Rules, but I'm not sure.

Another way is to make you own token module to get it. [Token api](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) is one of the easiest api from drupal.

Comment: I am actually looking for something more handy for future projects. Something like token_logic module

Comment: What is token_logic module??